# If I like the Stack Overflow podcast, what other podcasts might the stackoverflow community recommend?

Tags: discussion, podcast

I really enjoy the podcast and would like to listen to other IT/programming podcasts.  I am also listening to TWISt, which was recommended on one of the Stack Overflow podcasts, and like it as well.  In addition, I'm subscribed to IT conversations.  Are there any other podcasts that are popular among the Stack Overflow community that I could check out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826752/what-good-computer-science-podcasts-are-out-there) on this with a bunch of answers, it appears it has been deleted though.

Comment: Just found this through search, but link is now dead it seems.

Comment: Looks like the post was deleted, it was probably off topic based on the newer criteria.